# When I edit the tag 'learn react' to 'learn react pranjal' in app.js and then save and reload it no change is observed in browser, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I edit the tag 'learn react' to 'learn react pranjal' in app.js and then save and reload it no change is observed in browser, why?

```
  function App() {
     return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
               Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn react pranjal
            </a>
          </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: after i edit something in app.js and save it and try to reload it the changes doesnt appear

Answer (score 0):

What do you write in your terminal to run it?

Depending on what you write to run the react app the update-on-save function might not be working.

If you are using npm in WSL2.0 for development, please refer the last point in this- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/troubleshooting/#npm-start-doesnt-detect-changes

While WSL1.0 doesn't use a VM, WSL2.0 does use a lightweight VM, so adding

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

in a .env file in the project directory fixed the problem.

Comment: i write npm start in terminal

Comment: I use visual studio